# Algorithm Problem: Finding all cells that has distance of K from some specific cells in a 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, recursive-datastructures

there is a problem I have been thinking on for a while but cannot find efficient algorithm for. it is similar to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230069/binary-matrix-find-all-cells-with-distance-k). I have a 2D grid, some cells with 1, other cells are 0. now I need to find all 0 cells that have no more than distance of K from ALL other 1 cells. so how many eligible cell would be? I know brute force, which for every single ZERO cell check with all other 1 cell. if n^2 /2 are 0 and n^2/2 are one, then time complexity would be O(n^4). but it is not best algorithm (it's not HW or project just an ACM question I cannot solve )
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0

if K =2 then
0 0 X 1
0 0 X X
0 0 1 X
0 0 0 0

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69075779/16757174)